# Using a Boolean to cancel thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371293/is-event-set-the-preferred-way-to-stop-a-thread) to this on SO, but after re-reading it this morning, I realized it wasn't clear what I'm asking. So I narrowed down my problem and realized it was about a pattern instead of a coding problem.

I found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330877/should-i-use-a-boolean-or-a-cancellation-token-to-stop-this-task/330879?newreg=a25057ce6c2740609f24264fffc92b00) question, but it's related to C# and `Tasks`, but it's along the same lines.

Suppose I'm using a thread to download a file with the option of cancelling:

```
import threading

class DownloadThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._keep_download_active = True

    def run(self):
        while self.keep_download_active):
            # code to download file

    def cancel(self):
        self._keep_download_active = false
```

Python does have [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) objects. According to the docs:

> This is one of the simplest mechanisms for communication between
>   threads: one thread signals an event and other threads wait for it

Much like the C# link stated about `CancellationToken`, `Event` is thread-safe. Which means I can write my code like this:

```
import threading

class DownloadThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):

        # threading.Event() is false by default
        self._stop_download = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while self._stop_download:
            # code to download file

    def cancel(self):
        self._stop_download.set()
```

Notice, in the first example I'm not passing a `boolean` into the constructor, I'm declaring it in the `constructor`, and it's kept private (`_` indicates to the reader to treat it as private).

Given this current context, is doing so considered code smell? Would it be better to use what is provided by the language, in this case the second example?

If the `boolean` was passed into the `constructor`, then I can see it being a code smell, because then that variable might be shared across multiple threads and cause race conditions.

Comment: You can avoid a race condition by allowing one-time-only use of the cancel mechanism (the user can't un-cancel it, once it is cancelled).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - In that case I would check to see if it's already cancelled, if so do nothing. Correct?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - So either way, the `boolean` or `event` is acceptable. Just ensure once it's been cancelled that nothing happens.

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this.  Cancelling your download is going to move execution to somewhere else that doesn't look at the cancellation variable anymore, so I don't even think you have a race condition in the first place.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291069/is-python-variable-assignment-atomic